# How to compare table data between Redshift and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to test database replication from SQL Server to AWS Redshift. These two database's have the same tables and same table data. However, I want to check if there are any differences between the data in these tables.

Could anyone help me with any tool to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: In general, this is a coding question site where we  answer specific questions to specific coding problems. If you have code you've tried that doesn't work, please post it.

Comment: That's impossible to answer without *any* information. Are there IDs, timestamps, any identifying characteristics? "Find the difference" means get rows from each source *somewhere* and compare them. Either download all data into a local machine or move data from one system to the other, then do an OUTER join. And Redshift doesn't perform that well with joins.

Comment: You can create linked servers  for azure on onprem ,not sure redshift offers the same

Comment: @TheGameiswar using a linked server still pushes all input data to one machine for evaluation. Which is why remote joins aren't used to identify changes

Comment: What is the *actual problem*? Why compare both databases? For replication? Loading to Redshift? There are far better ways to do this, eg. by enabling Change Tracking and/or CDC on SQL Server, or using the replication infrastructure. Once you identify the changes, you can push them to Redshift

Comment: The data replication from MSSQL server to Redshift is done by other developers. I'm a tester, so my task is to ensure data of all tables in Redshift is exact the same as in MSSQL server. I've thought of exporting data of both databases to CSV and import to a local machine then do a query to compare like @PanagiotisKanavos suggestion. I know some tools for SQL data comparison, but they do not support Redshift.

Comment: That was a worst case suggestion. If you can pull Redshift's data into SQL Server, that would be a lot faster. Or push SQL Server's data to Redshift. That won't prove much though, only that your *files* are the same. What about next week? You can perform some quick checks by comparing counts and quick aggregations. These quick checks can be used for regular, daily testing of the data warehouse

Comment: Also note that SQL Server 2016SP1 allows columnstores, partitions etc even in SQL Server Express. You could use eg columnstores to quickly load a lot of data and perform quick aggregations. Perhaps, even faster than Redshift itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. It would be better if there is any tool that support my situation. DB Solo allows to connect Redshift but Compare function doesn't work for RDBMS :(. In the worst case, I'll pull Redshift's data into SQL server. Quick check by comparing counts are the good solution for checking after every scheduled job.

Comment: I have implemented something similar to regularly check daily that 2 separate databases are aligned. To do this I implemented a hashing routine on each table on each database, and then combined the outputs and compared the hashes.